# Hypothesis test in Bayesian statistics

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution, bayesian, hypothesis-testing

> Let $X\sim N(\theta,1)$ and 5 independent observations
>   $X=(4.9,5.6,5.1,4.6,3.6)$. The prior probability that $\theta=4.01$ is
>   $0.5$. The remain values of $\theta$ are given the density of
>   $g(\theta)$.
>
> a)Assume $g(\theta)\sim N(4.01,1)$ test the hypothesis
>   $$H_0:\theta=4.01\space vs\space H_1:\theta\neq 4.01$$

From what I learn to make a hypothesis test I need to find $$a_0=P(\theta\in\Theta_0|x)$$
such that $$a_0+a_1=1$$
and reject $H_0$ if $$a_0<a_1$$
in the cases where the null hypothesis is not a point I can make, but in this case I have a few doubts.

From the notes that I take there is the theorem below

> **Theorem:** For any prior $$\pi(\theta)=\pi_0\space \text{if}\space \theta=\theta_0$$ $$\pi(\theta)=\pi_1 h(\theta)\space\text{if}\space
>  \theta\neq \theta_0$$ such that $$\int_{\theta\neq
> > \theta_0}g(\theta)d(\theta)=1$$ then $$a_0=f(\theta|x)\geq
>  [1+\frac{1-\pi_0}{\pi_0}\frac{r(x)}{f(x|\theta_0)}]^{-1}$$ where
>   $$r(x)=sup_{\theta\neq\theta_0}f(x|\theta)$$ usually
>   $$r(x)=f(x|\hat{\theta})$$

In this case $\hat{\theta}=\overline{X}$ but the distribution of $$f(x|\overline{X})$$
doesn't make sense to me, in one example that I look they take $$f(\overline{x}|\hat{\theta})$$
but I don't understood the logic.

I need to use the distribution of the likelihood estimator supposing that $\theta=\hat{\theta}$?

If someone can give me a explanation with details on how it works I really appreciate.